# conversion of query used in Spring jdbc to db2

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc

I am completely new to spring jdbc, I came across a situation where I need to convert sql used in spring jdbc configuration file to plain db2 format. 
For example below is the query used (inside value tag) in the spring conf file, which I want to change to run against db2
i browse many spring documentation but failed to find any relative information, can someone point me to the link or the solution to this sql formatting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- JNDI DataSource for J2EE environment. -->
    <bean id="mi.conv.batch.dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.WebSphereDataSourceAdapter">
        <property name="targetDataSource">
            <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSourceInternal" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/Database" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction manager that delegates to JTA (use it when running within a container) -->     
    <bean id="mi.conv.batch.TransactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/> 


    <!-- Transactional proxy for data access facade. -->
    <bean id="mi.conv.batch.transactionProxyParent" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean" abstract="true">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="x.y.z.TransactionManager"/>
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
                <prop key="add*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="statementsDao" parent="x.y.z.transactionProxyParent">
        <property name="target">
            <bean class="abc.test.TestDaoImpl">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="a.b.c.dataSource"/>
                <property name="insertNotificationPreferenceSql">
                    <value>
                        select
                            NOTIFICATIONKY
                        from new table (
                            insert into 
                                NOTIFICATION (
                                    ID,
                                    PERSONKY,
                                    INSTANCEKY
                                )
                                **select
                                    (substr( ba.CODE, 1, 2 ) || '1111' || RIGHT( ba.CODE, 4 ) ||
                                        (case substr( ba.CODE, 1, 2 )
                                            when 'XY' then ''
                                            else '2222'
                                        end)
                                    || '0000' || ba.ACCTID ) as ID,
                                    cp.PERSONKY,
                                    ba.INSTANCEKY
                                from
                                    BCSACCT ba
                                    join
                                    PERSON cp on ( 1=1 )
                                where cp.PERSONKY = :personId
                                  and ba.INSTANCEKY = :prodinstId**
                        )                       
                    </value>                
                </property>                                         
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Comment: The query in the value tag IS the DB2 SQL.

Comment: Are you using the same SQL for a database other than DB2? If you need one SQL statement for DB2 and another for a different database, you'll have to copy the Spring XML config file and maintain the statements separately, unless you're using a newer Spring which supports profiles, in which case you can apply a profile name to each `<bean>` that needs something specific to DB2.

Comment: No its for single DB, & thanks for the clarification it clarifies all the things to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the plain DB2 formated sql would be the string entity within your "value" quotes.  I try running the exact same query through a SQL client connected to a TEST copy of the database and see if you get the results you are looking for.

```
select NOTIFICATIONKY
from new table (
     insert into NOTIFICATION (
         ID,
         PERSONKY,
         INSTANCEKY
     )
     **select ( substr( ba.CODE, 1, 2 ) || 
                '1111'                  || 
                RIGHT( ba.CODE, 4 )     || 
                (case substr( ba.CODE, 1, 2 ) when 'XY' then '' else '2222' end) || 
                '0000'                  || 
                ba.ACCTID ) as ID,
                cp.PERSONKY,
                ba.INSTANCEKY
     from BCSACCT ba
     join PERSON cp on ( 1=1 )
     where cp.PERSONKY = :personId
     and ba.INSTANCEKY = :prodinstId**
)
```

You might be having problems with the SQL statement; I tried to clean the indentation up a bit to make sense of it.  This statement looks to insert rows into a table called "NOTIFICATION", where the ID field is some a mess figured out from a mess of ORs on the BCSACCT.CODE or BCSACCT.ACCTID, the PERSONKY and INSTANCEKY are pretty straight forward.

Quick explanation:
Spring Beans are java classes that are managed with the Spring Inversion of Control Container. Information in your xml file defines several properties that the related Java Bean uses when the class is initialized by Spring. In your XML file, it appears that the property "insertNotificationPreferenceSql" is referenced by the Java bean in the class code.  The JDBCTemplate class actually runs the SQL, but the Java Bean code needs to be investigated to see how that property is actually being used.